# Solution to drop down menu tkinter issue

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I am currently working on a python GUI application to which a user can search for changes in stock market prices so on. I am trying to create a search history type drop down menu, to which I'm having no luck. Each company that a user enters get stored to a text file, which the program then reads from the individual user's text file, which then forms the search history. The way I have set my code up is that a for loop is run to add new commands to the drop down menu, with labels corresponding to each company the user had previously searched for. However, I need to get the value of the label in order to run a search for the details of the stock prices.

```
 def CreateMenu(self):
    menu=Menu(self.window2)
    self.subMenu=Menu(menu)
    self.window2.config(menu=menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Search History", menu=self.subMenu)
    f=open(self.entered_text+'.txt','r+')
    for line in f:
        self.subMenu.add_command(label=line, command=self.getdata)
```

So here I'm creating a new command in the menu dropdown for each piece of data in the text file. When the user selects one of the commands, how can I get either the label of that particular command in the menu or the index? 
I know the .entrycget function but i'd need to know the position of the command being selected, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use `lambda` to pass an argument to the function:

```
for line in f:
    self.subMenu.add_command(label=line, 
        command=lambda label=line: self.getdata(label))
```

You then need to modify `getdata` to accept a parameter:

```
def self.getdata(self, label):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that!

Answer (score 0):

For a self-contained example,

```
from tkinter import *

def go(line):
    print(line)

root = Tk()

menu=Menu(root)
subMenu=Menu(menu)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Search History", menu=subMenu)
commands = []
f=open('search_menu.txt','r+') # text file with one search entry per line
for line in f:
    commands.append(subMenu.add_command(label=line[:-1], command=lambda x=line[:-1]:go(x)))

# [:-1] is getting rid of \n

root.mainloop()
```